# Abrir la galería desde mi aplicación por medio de un botón

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Estoy iniciándome en Android, y necesito abrir desde mi aplicación la galería de imágenes o el explorador de archivos, para ver las ultimas fotos tomadas desde la cámara.

Lo único que tengo es el siguiente método, pero no se que mas siga, me podrían ayudar por favor?

estoy utilizando Android Studio en su ultima versión.

```
public void GALERIA(View view) {

Intent intent  = new Intent();
```

Gracias.

Comment: Removí la etiqueta [tag:google-apps-script] porque o tiene que ver con lo que se está preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba este código.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: ¿Y que realiza este código?, hay que agregar una descripción. Revisar [answer] , saludos!.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono muy bien!!!!